# Laravel fresh installation via softaculous - File not found

Tags: php, laravel, installation, softaculous

i tried installing Laravel 5.7 from Softaculous

it showed no error, installation was successful

but when i go to the installation URL, it says :

File not found.

i tried deleting and reinstalling, even reinstalling in a different path... i get the same error

help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by running command for httpdocs folder:-

> sudo chmod a+rwx httpdocs

Somehow this folder was only accessible to root user.